# ContentEditor Div repositions caret while typing, in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having a react application, and building a Text editor using a div tag. in the div I've enabled content-editor True. and binding it with useState variable. That useState variable directly binded with text-editor Div tag with dangerouslySetInnerHTML. like follows.

```
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')
```

```
function onChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const val = e.target.innerHTML;
        setContent(val)
            console.log(content);
    }
```

```
<div  contentEditable="true" onInput={onChange} className='Editor' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={content}/>
```

Here problem is while typing in the editor. caret moves first index (beginning). and adding values at first

like if " type 'apple',
but editor adding like 'elppa'

any solution you know please put in the answer

I've tried many things as chatGPT told but there is no solution working

Answer (score 1):

After some time checking, I don't think you actually need to include `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={content}`.
Because for each letter you type, its innerHTML will be re-rendered with the letter you last typed, and for each re-render the caret will understandably reposition itself at the start.
Hope it makes sense for you.